# How to fix this error in terminal while writing hello world code in VS Code on C?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, terminal

```
PS C:\Users\Rohit Pradhan\C Tutorials> gcc main.c

gcc.exe: error: main.c: No such file or directory

gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files

compilation terminated.
```

[Was trying to get this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we5rL.png)

[Getting this error after typing "gcc main.c", trying to run a.exe in my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oWjG.png)

Comment: Your file is in `main/main.c` and you are compiling `main.c`. It's what it says `main.c: No such file or directory`

Comment: Type "cd main"  in your terminal to move in the main directory, after that compile